# Add text shipping value in Opencart

Tags: php, mysql, opencart

We provide emailed quotes after an order is recieved in OpenCart. How can I add a field to show TBC instead of £0.00 in OpenCart. We use X-Shipping for our 4 delivery options:

Is this possible?

Here is the PHP code for the catalog side

```
<?php
class ModelShippingXshipping extends Model {
function getQuote($address) {
    $this->load->language('shipping/xshipping');

    $method_data = array();
    $quote_data = array();



        for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++)
        {



            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "zone_to_geo_zone WHERE geo_zone_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('xshipping_geo_zone_id'.$i) . "' AND country_id = '" . (int)$address['country_id'] . "' AND (zone_id = '" . (int)$address['zone_id'] . "' OR zone_id = '0')");

            if (!$this->config->get('xshipping_geo_zone_id'.$i)) {
                $status = true;
            } elseif ($query->num_rows) {
                $status = true;
            } else {
                $status = false;
            }



            if (!$this->config->get('xshipping_status'.$i)) {
              $status = false;
            }

            if (!$this->config->get('xshipping_name'.$i)) {
              $status = false;
            }

            $shipping_cost=$this->config->get('xshipping_cost'.$i);
            $free_shipping_cost=(float)$this->config->get('xshipping_free'.$i);
            if(empty($free_shipping_cost))$free_shipping_cost=0;

            if ($this->cart->getSubTotal() >= $free_shipping_cost && $free_shipping_cost!=0) {
                $shipping_cost = 0;

            }


            if ($status) {

                $quote_data['xshipping'.$i] = array(
                    'code'         => 'xshipping'.'.xshipping'.$i,
                    'title'        => $this->config->get('xshipping_name'.$i),
                    'cost'         => $shipping_cost,
                    'tax_class_id' => $this->config->get('xshipping_tax_class_id'.$i),
                    'text'         => $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($shipping_cost, $this->config->get('xshipping_tax_class_id'.$i),      $this->config->get('config_tax')))
                );


            }
        }

        if(!$quote_data) return array();

        $method_data = array(
            'code'       => 'xshipping',
            'title'      => $this->language->get('text_title'),
            'quote'      => $quote_data,
            'sort_order' => $this->config->get('xshipping_sort_order'),
            'error'      => ''
        );  


    return $method_data;
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi. You could change the line which is starting with `'text'` to something like this: `'text'         => ($shipping_cost == 0.00) ? 'TBC' : $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($shipping_cost, $this->config->get('xshipping_tax_class_id'.$i), $this->config->get('config_tax')))`. It would check if the price is 0.00, if it is, then it would change it to TBC.